# Calculate year week number from given period in VBScript

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic, week-number, datepart

**Scenario**: Trying to find out the **End Week Number**(current year's week number) and **Start Week Number** using a given period. Suppose **PeriodWeeks** = 10. That means from today's week number  to last 10 weeks which surely will go to last year in current situation.

**Code** I have:

```
perdiodWeeks = 10             ' this is a constant in the code
periodMonths= periodQtrs * 3  ' this calculates month from given number of quarters

endDate = DateAdd("m",-1,Date)
endYear = DatePart("yyyy", endDate)
endMonth = DatePart("m", endDate)

startDate = DateAdd("m", -(periodMonths-1), endDate)
startYear = DatePart("yyyy", startDate)
startMonth = DatePart("m", startDate)
```

How can I calculate the following?

```
startYW             ' start year week number
endYW               ' end year week number
```

where value would be **endYW** = 201506 and **startYW** = perdiodWeeks from endYW. 06 is the current Week Number of 2015

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calculate the initial date (substract #weeks*7) and use the available functions to retrieve the required information

```
Option Explicit

Dim periodWeeks
    periodWeeks = 10

Dim dateToday, dateStart
    dateToday = Now()
    dateStart = DateAdd("d",periodWeeks*-7, dateToday)

Dim weekToday, weekStart
    weekToday = DatePart("ww",dateToday)
    weekStart = DatePart("ww",dateStart)
```